# Is there a way to fully extend a language configuration, including completion providers?

Tags: monaco-editor

When registering a new monaco language, we can copy the configuration and language settings from other existing languages to extend them. However, there does not seem to be a way to clone other providers like definition and completion item providers. This makes extending/cloning languages much more difficult. Am I missing something, or is there really no way to do this?